# How to purge/delete message from weblogic JMS queue clustered environment

Tags: jms, weblogic

I am having trouble in executing the program in the below link.

[How to purge/delete message from weblogic JMS queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461870/how-to-purge-delete-message-from-weblogic-jms-queue)

Mine is a clustered environment and using the `DomainRuntimeServiceMBean` in the service.

Getting the below exception.

```
 javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: 
 com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,
 Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean
```

However the single node runs fine but there are no JMS servers it identified as mine in a cluster environment.

Do I need to provide the particular server name under the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The `DomainRuntimeServiceMBean` is available only on the administrative instance of the WebLogic domain (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/wlsmbeanref/mbeans/DomainRuntimeServiceMBean.html?skipReload=true).

You need to connect to the administrative instance of the domain, not to one of the cluster instances to avoid the `javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException` error.

So please check which instance you are connecting to.